# Point2D equals within threshold

Tags: java, equals, point, euclidean-distance

I have to write a `Point2D` class for an assignment and so far I have been able to write the code for all the necessary methods except the `equals()` methods.

I'm having trouble figuring how to write the code for it. The `equals` method is supposed to detect points that represent the same location, **within a distance threshold**.

Here is the code which I have so far:

```
public class Point2D {

    final private double x;
    final private double y;

    /**
     * Constructor to initialize coordinates
     * 
     * @param x x value
     * @param y y value
     */
    public Point2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * Get the x coordinate
     * 
     * @return x coordinate
     */
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * Get the y coordinate
     * 
     * @return y coordinate
     */
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a String representation
     * of the coordinate in the form
     * "(x, y)" (each with three decimal
     * places of precision)
     * 
     * @return "(x, y)"
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + String.format("%.3f", x) + "," + String.format(" %.3f", y) + ")"; 
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if provided another
     * point that is at the same (x,y)
     * location (that is, the distance
     * is "close enough" according to
     * Shape2D)
     * 
     * @param o another object
     * @return true if the other object is a point and the same location (within threshold)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

    }

    /**
     * Method to compute the Euclidean/L2
     * distance between two points in 2D
     * space
     * 
     * @param p1 point 1
     * @param p2 point 2
     * @return straightline distance between p1 and p2
     */
    public static double distance(Point2D p1, Point2D p2) {
         return Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)); 
    }

    /**
     * Method to compute the Euclidean
     * distance between this point
     * and a supplied point
     * 
     * @param p input point
     * @return straightline distance between this point and p
     */
    public double distanceTo(Point2D p) {
        return Math.sqrt((p.x - x) * (p.x - x) + (p.y - y) * (p.y - y)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `instanceof`, cast and then you just call `distanceTo(other)` and check if its below the threshold `< threshold`. Thats it. And you might want to do some validation checks beforehand, like `null` and type.

Comment: Note that whenever overriding `equals` you must also override `hashCode` with the same logic, otherwise you will run into a lot of issues (for example `set.add(point)` and then `set.contains(point)` saying `false`). This is part of the contract of `equals`. Might be difficult to implement `hashCode` with such a logic. At least if you try to avoid hash collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instanceof` operator to test the type of another object to check if it can be cast.

```java
Object obj =  // ...
if (obj instanceof Point2D) {
    Point2D otherPoint = (Point2D) obj;
    // Now you can compare otherPoint to this
}
```

Comment: ... and then? You might want to give a full example, showing how to do the actual condition "distance below threshold".